# How to force override Component->File with WiX during installation?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3

I am trying to overwrite a config.properties file with my WiX setup. I use systemtools:TemplateFile to replace placeholders in a template file. But the setup fails to update it since it has been changed.

I tried several things like adding RemoveFile before the systemtools:TemplateFile but it failed. I am not sure if there is any good solution to this problem.

Currently we use it like this:

```xml
<Directory Id="CONFIGS" Name="Configurations">
  <Component Id="APP_CONF_FILE" Win64="no" Guid="UNIQUEUUID">
    <File Id="rms.properties" Name="config.properties" Source="data\config.properties" />
    <systemtools:TemplateFile Id="component.properties" 
      Source="[CONFIGS]config.properties"
      Target="[CONFIGS]config.properties"
      ExecuteOnInstall="yes">
      <systemtools:TemplateFileProperty Id="version_property" Name="version" Value="$(var.Version)" />
    </systemtools:TemplateFile>
  </Component>
</Directory>
```

The MSI log shows this:

> MSI (s) (0C:6C) [15:22:20:922]: File: C:\Program Files (x86)\COMPANY\PRODUCT\conf\config.properties;  Won't Overwrite;    Won't patch;    Existing file is unversioned but modified

Is there any way to force replace it or remove it before?
It should always be overwritten during an installation.

Comment: when you're trying to overwrite? During patching, major upgrade?

Comment: @VivekJaiswal it should always override. Only uninstall should remove the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking during patching, check the [REINSTALLMODE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/reinstallmode) property. By default, Its value is "omus".If you want to replace files forcely, use "amus".